# How to fill a rectangle with an image in paperJS?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, paperjs

I need to fill a rectangle with an image. I've tried Raster but I am not able to figure out how to use raster inside the rectangle created on the canvas.

Is there a function similar to fillColor() method for filling the rectangle with an image rather than colors?

Any hints/tips or a sample fiddle would be great!

Comment: Welcome to SO. We’re not here to create code you need. Please provide what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: html5 `canvas` supports `drawImage`... see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images#Drawing_images

Comment: @KittMedia  sometimes it is better to not write code at all, if the best you can get is something ugly and convoluted. I mean - why spend an hour on writing code just to have something to post on SO, when there is a high chance a person with paper.js skills will be able to solve the problem in a few lines? That's one of my gripes with SO - you will get downvoted just because you didn't want to post something that you know will not work or will be ugly as hell.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) is what you can do:

```
// Create your raster:
var url = 'http://assets.paperjs.org/images/marilyn.jpg';
var raster = new Raster(url);
raster.position = new Point(300,300);

// Use clipMask to create a custom polygon clip mask:
var path = new Path.Rectangle(150,150,100,150);
path.clipMask = true;

// It is better to add the path and the raster in a group (but not mandatory)

/*
var group = new Group();
group.addChild(raster);
group.addChild(path);
*/


// If you just need a rectangle part of a raster, you could use getSubRaster(rect) instead:
/*
var subRaster = raster.getSubRaster(new Rectangle(150,150,100,150));
subRaster.position = new Point(600,600);
*/
```